# How to print last word that contain field seperator

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, sed, rhel

How to print the last  field (`word3,a,b,c,d,e`), that contains the field separator `,`?

- in each line we have only 3 words/strings as the following structure

  **type,parameter,value**

but the value can include the unescaped field separator itself. Example from line:

```
echo word1,word2,word3,a,b,c,d,e | awk -F "," '{print $3}'
```

its print:

```
word3
```

expected results:

```
word3,a,b,c,d,e
```

other example

```
echo 32637,921763.373,str84,str42,struj,str56,str65 | awk -F "," '{print $3}'
```

expected results:

```
str84,str42,struj,str56,str65
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for `cut`: `echo word1,word2,word3,a,b,c,d,e | cut -d, -f3-`

Comment: ok go on it please publish your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the last field in `word1,word2,word3,a,b,c,d,e` is `e` and the third field is `word3`. It looks like you want the part of the line starting with the third field. It's easier with `cut`:

```
$ echo word1,word2,word3,a,b,c,d,e | cut -d , -f 3-
word3,a,b,c,d,e
```

`-f 3-` is `-f x-y` for fields x to y, but with `y` omitted, so it's from 3<sup>rd</sup> to  last field.

Note that it assumes the lines contain at least 3 fields. It would give empty output lines for input lines that contain 2 fields, and leave the line untouched if it contained no comma (you can add a `-s` option to skip the non-delimited lines):

```
$ printf '%s\n' a a,b a,b,c a,b,c,d | cut -d , -f 3-
a

c
c,d
$ printf '%s\n' a a,b a,b,c a,b,c,d | cut -sd , -f 3-

c
c,d
```

With `awk`, you could do:

```
$ printf '%s\n' a a,b a,b,c a,b,c,d | awk 'sub(/^[^,]*,[^,]*,/, "")'
c
c,d
```

<sup>(the `awk 'sub(/^([^,]*,){2}/, "")'` variant, though POSIX, is less portable as there are still a few `awk` implementations that don't support the `{x,y}` regexp operator)</sup>

To delete the first 2 fields (and only print the lines where they have been removed), though that would be using `awk` as a glorified `sed` as that's the same as `sed -n 's/^[^,]*,[^,]*,//p'`.

Or:

```
$ printf '%s\n' a a,b a,b,c a,b,c,d | awk 'sub(/^[^,]*,?[^,]*,?/, "")'


c
c,d
```

to print an empty line for lines that have fewer than 3 fields.

Answer (score 2):

The `awk` way would be:

```
awk -F "," '{for(i=3;i<NF;i++)printf("%s,", $i);print $NF}'
```

But it sounds like a job for `cut`:

```
cut -d , -f 3-
```

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`, making use of its array-slice feature (avoiding the need for a `for` loop as in `awk`):

```
$ echo word1,word2,word3,a,b,c,d,e | perl -F, -lane 'print join(",",@F[2..$#F])'
word3,a,b,c,d,e
```

Explanation of `perl` command-line options used (see `man perlrun` for more details):

- `-F,` set field separator for autosplit to `,`
- `-l` enables automatic line-ending processing (i.e. automatically strip newlines from the end of each input line and add them to each `print`-ed output line).
- `-a` turn on autosplit mode - each input line is automatically split into an array `@F`.
- `-n` read and process each line of stdin and/or any filename arguments (essentially, a `while(<>)` loop around the entire script)
- `-e` execute the next argument (the quoted string) as a perl script.

Note: `perl` arrays are zero-based, not one-based, so the third field is array element 2, not 3  (that is, `@F[2]`, **not** `@F[3]`).

`$#F` is the index number of the final element of array `@F`, so `@F[2..$#F]` means "all elements of the array `@F` from the third to the last".

---

BTW, there is another option `-p` which is very similar to `-n` except that at the end of each pass through the `while(<>)` loop, it also prints the input line.  If the input line has been modified by any prior statements then the line is printed as modified.

One of the uses for this is that it allows you to write very `sed`-like scripts in `perl` (but with all the features and syntactic sugar of `perl` in addition to `sed`).   e.g. `perl -pe 's/foo/bar/g'` and `sed -e 's/foo/bar/g'` will have identical output given the same input.

Similarly, `-n` combined with `-a` makes it easy to write very `awk`-like scripts.  In fact, `perl -lane` is pretty much the standard way to write an `awk`-like one-liner with `perl`.

One of the strengths of `perl` is that it combines the features of `sed` and of `awk` (and of `tr`) and a whole lot more, including access to a huge library of modules called the "Comprehensive Perl Archive Network" or [CPAN](http://cpan.org/)

Answer (score 0):

With this you're done

```
echo 32637,921763.373,str84,str42,struj,str56,str65 | awk -F "," '{ for(i = 3; i < NF+1; i++) printf "%s%s",$i,(i!=NF?",":"");}'
```

but anyway, you need to read awk docs.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
sed 's/^\([^,]*,\)\{0,2\}//' <<<"$line"
```